# c++ matrix calculations

Tags: c++, matrix

I have created the following problem which (for now) is going to calculate the determinant or a matrix.( I will expand it that's why I input the dimensions and the matrices).

EDITED--->>> The problem which remains :

- It doesn't recognize the variables "mat  " in my functions.

error: ‘mat’ was not declared in this scope

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <cstdlib> 
 #include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class matrix {
private:
int rows,columns;

public:
//constructor
matrix ()
{}
matrix(int _rows,int _columns) : rows(_rows),columns(_columns){
{
 int **mat=new int *[rows];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        mat[r] = new int[columns];
}

}
//destructor
~matrix(){
for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        delete[] mat[r];
    delete[] mat;

}

//void allocate();
void getdata() {

cout <<"Enter number of rows :"<<endl;
cin >>rows;
cout <<"Enter number of columns : "<<endl;
cin >> columns;

}
void fill();
double determinant();
void showdata(){

}

};



int main()
{
matrix a;

a.getdata();
a.fill();
a.determinant();

    return 0;
}



//fills the matrix
void matrix ::fill(){

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
        cout <<"Enter the elements in a line separated by whitespace :"<<endl;
        cin >>mat[i][j];
        }
    }

}
//calculate the determinant
double matrix :: determinant (){
    double det;
    det = mat[rows][columns]*mat[rows+1][columns+1] - mat[rows][columns+1]*mat[rows+1][columns];
    cout <<"The determinant of matrix is :"<<det<<endl;}
```

Comment: The function determinant() introduces local variables i and j without declaring them. rows and columns are uninitialised and so your matrix could be of any random dimension and you may well get bad_alloc in your constructor

Comment: @CashCow:Οκ ,thanks!You are right! Could you tell me how i must write the constructor?Because i can't get it work!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is initialize `mat` to be an array of dynamic size.  This cannot be done in, as your compiler tells you, a constant expression.

You must write a constructor for the `matrix` class which will take `rows` as a parameter and contain the `mat=new int *[rows]` line.  Note that you'll also need to initialize *each* row of `mat`; your `allocate` method does this and should be called from the constructor.

Comment: If i got it well.I am deleting the "int **mat..from private".I do :matrix () {
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++) {int **mat=new int *[rows];
mat[i]=new int [columns];
}
}; (putting the allocate) It still doesn;t recognize "mat , i ,j"

Comment: @George: You need `int** mat;` in the `matrix` declaration.  You also need that code you have above in a **constructor**.  To access the variable, try `mat[i][j]`.  Not `mat , i , j`.

Answer (score 0):

`new` operator dynamically allocates memory ( i.e., from the free store ). So, it should be part of any member function to assign its return address to a member variable in this example and not the part of class declaration. It can be a part of your `getdata()` member function.

And also, class requires a **destructor** because it is managing resources.

**Edit 1 :**

Problems -

1. `int **mat=new int *[rows];`, is a local variable in the parameterized constructor and goes out of scope once the call to the constructor is done raising memory leaks.
2. With the statement, `matrix a;`, the default constructor will be called. i.e., `matrix::matrix()`, the constructor with no arguments. However, you are making your initialization in the parameterized constructor.

To make everything work, try this -

```
class matrix
{
    int **mat;
    // ...

    public:
    matrix()
    {
        cout <<"Enter number of rows :"<<endl;
        cin >>rows;
        cout <<"Enter number of columns : "<<endl;
        cin >> columns;

        mat=new int *[rows];
        for (int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            mat[i]=new int [columns];
        }
    }

    // And no more, getdata() member function is required. Avoid it's call in main()
};
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: @Mahesh: Hello,i tried it but still doesn't recognize the "mat,i,j" in my functions

Comment: @Mahesh:Hello,i did it as you say right now and it worked!It asks for rows,columns and then the elements of the matrix.But in the end it gives me"segmentation fault"and no result of the determinant.

Comment: @Mahesh:Obviously,i cannot find a way to insert the values i am taking from function fill into function determinant..

Comment: In the `determinant()`, trying to access the elements past the array. i.e., `mat[rows][columns]*mat[rows+1][columns+1] - mat[rows][columns+1]*mat[rows+1][columns];`. When array size is 5, array index starts from 0 to 4. There is no array[5]. Now, change the above statement accordingly.

Comment: @Mahesh:I understand the indexing but i can't figure how i will manage it here,in this case.If i had a matrix[1][1] i know that it starts from 0 to 1,so i have a 2 size matrix.But,here i can't figure how to put it in determinant function...

Comment: In that case to make the code clear, have a class variable that has the size of the matrix. Also, I think the determinant calculation is incorrect. Isn't the row/column the size of the matrix, since determinant is associated with square matrices.

Comment: @Mahesh:I am giving as input a 2x2 matrix and it gives me that error.Anyway,i am working on it now..

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you've variable size for your matrix and that your matrix data is going to be in the heap, you've to initialize your matrix data in the constructor or by lazy instantiation. I had previously answered a question for creating a matrix. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070317/question-on-arrays-in-c/3070710#3070710) to it. If you look in there you can observe that data is not initialised before the size of the matrix is known and as in your case it's created in the heap memory.

**EDIT**: C++ does not allow initialisation of member variables in the heap when they are declared. And in your case the size of the matrix is not known in the first place for `mat` to be created with the right size of memory. As mentioned by everybody in here, use the constructor to create the `mat` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of `mat` belongs into the constructor, say

```
matrix::matrix(int _rows, int _columns)
: rows(_rows)
, columns(_columns)
, mat(new int *[rows])
{
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        mat[r] = new int[columns];
}
```

Do not forget the destructor:

```
matrix::~matrix()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        delete[] mat[r];
    delete[] mat;
}
```

This being said, I highly advice against inventing yet another "my great own matrix class library". Use something efficient and established such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/).

Also, for containers, unless you have really good reasons, use some good class library for that. E.g. the standard library with `std::vector` and so on, or (even better in my taste): Qt classes like QVector.

Comment: @Timan Vogel:Hello, i can't understand the first part that you are giving."matrix ::matrix(int_rows,int_columns) : rows(_rows),columns(_columns),mat(new int *[rows])" Is this a constructor?Because i know that a constructor defines as"matrix() :initial values {}".

Comment: @Timan Vogel: If i do "matrix (int rows,int columns) : rows(_rows), columns(_columns), mat(new int *[rows]) {

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        mat[r] = new int[columns];

}" ,in the class matrix ,in public, it gives me "_rows was not declared, _columns ....and of course the matrix constructor doesn't have any filed "mat"

Comment: The part behind `:` is the initializer list for the attributes (and possibly base classes if present). `_rows` and so on are just the parameters of the constructor. Maybe you missed adjusting the parameters of the constructor in the declaration? They need to match up. What do you mean by "the constructor doesn't have any field mat"? The constructor has access to all attributes of the constructed class, so `mat` or course refers to `matrix::mat` which is your proposed storage attribute.

Comment: Yeah, `mat` belongs in the class. Only now looked at your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

With your immediate question:

`mat` appears to be a local variable in your constructor and not a class member
`i` and `j` are local variables declared in `fill()` but not `determinant()`

There are other major issues:

- Your matrix does not initialize `rows` or `columns`. These will have any random value and given they are signed ints, could even be negative. Your constructor might well throw bad_alloc
- fill with what?
- That isn't the correct formula to get a determinant, which in any case only applies to square matrices
- You would be better off using vector rather than arrays and only one vector. Look at the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10) to see the simplest way to make a matrix.

  Assuming you do want it to be a matrix of int not double, declare "mat" this way:

  `std::vector<int> mat;`

Your constructor should be something like:

```
matrix::matrix (int r,int c) :
   rows(r), columns(c), mat(r*c)
{
    //body
}
```

Overload operator[] thus:

```
int* operator[](int r)
{
    return &mat[r*columns];
}

const int* operator[](int r) const
{
    return &mat[r*columns];
}
```

Note we have 2 of them. It is possible to implement one in terms of the other. Some also like to overload operator() to take 2 parameters, row and column, but the above will work.

You might prefer to use size_t rather than int for dimensions.

Comment: Note for anyone reading he has modified the question since I answered so obviously bugs I pointed out are no longer there.

Comment: Hello,i still have the problem with not recognizing "mat".I edited my post.What else can i do?Thank you..

Comment: @George mat is not a member of the class. You declared it as a local variable