# How to declare dynamically sized array fields in C++ class?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, class

I am C++ newbie.

I want to have class which has 5 arrays as fields.
Size of these arrays should be initialize dynamically.

I have written some code, but this isn't working right know:

```
class ParsedData {
  public:
    int generators_count;
    double mean_arr[generators_count];
    double variance_arr[generators_count];
    int amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr[generators_count];
    int intervals_count;
    double interval_begins_arr[intervals_count];
    double interval_ends_arr[intervals_count];
};

ParsedData::ParsedData(int _generators_count, double[] _mean_arr, double[] _variance_arr, int[] _amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr,
    int _intervals_count, double[] _interval_begins_arr, double[] _interval_ends_arr) {
  generators_count = _generators_count;
  mean_arr = _mean_arr;
  variance_arr = _variance_arr;
  amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr = _amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr;
  intervals_count = _intervals_count;
  interval_begins_arr = _interval_begins_arr;
  interval_ends_arr = _interval_ends_arr;
}
```

Compilation error log:

```
z01.cpp:53:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘ParsedData::generators_count’
z01.cpp:54:21: error: from this location
z01.cpp:53:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘ParsedData::generators_count’
z01.cpp:55:25: error: from this location
z01.cpp:53:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘ParsedData::generators_count’
z01.cpp:56:43: error: from this location
z01.cpp:57:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘ParsedData::intervals_count’
z01.cpp:58:32: error: from this location
z01.cpp:57:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘ParsedData::intervals_count’
z01.cpp:59:30: error: from this location
z01.cpp:62:56: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘_mean_arr’
z01.cpp:62:1: error: prototype for ‘ParsedData::ParsedData(int, double*)’ does not match any in class ‘ParsedData’
z01.cpp:51:7: error: candidates are: ParsedData::ParsedData(const ParsedData&)
z01.cpp:51:7: error:                 ParsedData::ParsedData()
z01.cpp: In function ‘ParsedData load_input_data()’:
z01.cpp:102:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘ParsedData::ParsedData(int&, double [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)generators_count) + -1)) + 1)], double [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)generators_count) + -1)) + 1)], int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)generators_count) + -1)) + 1)], int&, double [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)intervals_count) + -1)) + 1)], double [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)intervals_count) + -1)) + 1)])’
z01.cpp:102:62: note: candidates are:
z01.cpp:51:7: note: ParsedData::ParsedData()
z01.cpp:51:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 7 provided
z01.cpp:51:7: note: ParsedData::ParsedData(const ParsedData&)
z01.cpp:51:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 7 provided
```

Any ways how to fix that?

Comment: Why not use a vector instead? `std::vector<double> interval_begins_arr`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070317/question-on-arrays-in-c/3070376#3070376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `std::vector` as follows.

```
class ParsedData {
    std::vector<double> mean_arr, variance_arr, interval_begins_arr, interval_ends_arr;
    std::vector<int> amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr;

    ParsedData(std::vector<double> mean_arr,
            std::vector<double> variance_arr,
            std::vector<double> interval_begins_arr,
            std::vector<double> interval_ends_arr,
            std::vector<int> amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr)
        : mean_arr(mean_arr), variance_arr(variance_arr)
        , interval_begins_arr(interval_begins_arr), interval_ends_arr(interval_ends_arr)
        , amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr(amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr) {}
}
```

you can convert a c++ array or pointer to a vector with:

```
int count = 5;
int a[count] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> vec_a(a, a+5);
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector<double>`. The size of a C-style array must be a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you would use an `std::vector<double>`, and initialize it to the required size int he constructor. For example:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
 public:
  Foo(int i) : intervals_count(i), interval_begins_arr(intervals_count) {}
 private:
  int intervals_count;
  std::vector<double> interval_begins_arr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int generators_count;
double mean_arr[generators_count];
```

when you are initializing the class, generators_count does not have a value, which means that you can't use it to determine the size of the array. Can you use std::vector instead?

Comment: that is his code that I quoted. I realize it's not standards compliant.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to read correctly today.

Answer (score 1):

use a [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or use a `double*` then allocate with `new` (only if the size will not change after the initial allocation)

An array requires the size to be known at compile time

Answer (score 1):

If `generators_count` and `intervals_count` are known at compile-time [but not a single constant for the whole program], you could use `template`.

```
template <const int T1, const int T2>
class ParsedData {
  public:
    int generators_count;
    double mean_arr[T1];
    double variance_arr[T1];
    int amount_of_numbers_to_generate_arr[T1];
    int intervals_count;
    double interval_begins_arr[T2];
    double interval_ends_arr[T2];
};
```

Otherwise, as suggested elsewhere, use `vector`.

I personally like the suggestion of using a `struct` to hold the generators values and another `struct` for the interval data - saves on the number of vectors. [I would probably have done that before even coming up with this structure, since it makes life easier to see that all these belong together].

Answer (score 1):

Well. The first answer is: you should try `std::vector<double>.`

But looking at your code… what is your intention?

`ParsedData` as is in your code is only a kind of interface to the actual array with data, and you are not copying anything more that a reference (actually pointers) to it in ParsedData, but the data is somewhere else. Is this your intention?

If yes, you can use simple `double *maen_arr;` etc.

If no, and you need actually a copy of the data, then please consider using `vector`.